# adobe animate - publishing to I Phone

Tags: actionscript-3, jquery-animate, adobe, publishing

I have coded an application in adobe animate using as3 and have published it to my phone (I Phone 6, OS: IOS 12.4.4) for testing purposes.
I am getting black borders at the top and button of the application. This happens with any adobe animate file irrespective of stage-size or publishing-settings. Would anyone know how to fix this?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to provide appropriately sized launch images to signal that the app supports those sizes of device:

[Adobe AIR: Setting mobile application properties](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffe.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129907d2886-8000)